# Visual studio C programming function defenition

Tags: c++, function, sorting

The program below is to sort number in ascending order using a function. It is written in Visual Studio.

I know that I have made a mistake in function declaration as I have declared `int LinearSort();` above `main` and not inside `main`.

The program executes without error but sorting does not happen since the function is not called.

The program is saved as C++.

Can anyone help me to call the function and do sorting by editing program below?

**Main file**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdafx.h>
#include "sort.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

int LinearSort();

int main()
{
    int sort[50];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    int a = 0;

    printf("Enter 10 Numbers");

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) 
    {
        scanf_s("%d",&sort[i]);
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) 
    {
        printf("%d\n",sort[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

**.C file**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "sort.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

void LinearSort(int i, int j, int k, int a, int sort[])
{   
    for ( j=0; j < i-1; j++ )
    {
        for ( k=0; k < i-j-1; k++ )
        {
        if(sort[k] < sort[k+1])
        {
            a = sort[k];
            sort[k] = sort[k+1];
            sort[k+1] = a;
        }

        else
        {
            sort[j] = sort[j];
        }
    }
    }
    for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ ) 
    {
        printf("ascending %d\n",sort[j]);
    }
    _getch();

}
```

**Header file**

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>

extern void LinearSort(int i, int j, int k, int a, int sort[]);
```

Comment: `Enter 10 Numbers`...then why you have an array with 50 elements?

Comment: So why not call the `LinearSort` function from `main`? (And remove the bogus declaration `int LinearSort();` too.)

Comment: Why does your `LinearSort` function have so many parameters? Most of the parameters should be declared as local variables within the function. In particular, it looks like the `j`, `k` and `a` parameters should be changed to local variables, leaving the `i` parameter as the array length and the `sort` parameter as a pointer to the array contents.

Comment: That's not C! C++ is a different language. Use a C compiler to compile C code!

Comment: @Olaf why did you change the tag to C++ ? I think the op is clearly trying to write C code here. I don't see any `std::cout` but a lot of `printf()`. The only C++ish code i can find here is `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: @Skynet: 1) Please provide a reference to the C standard where `iostream` is a valid header (or omitting the `.h` is valid). 2) OP clearly staes he compiles as C++. This alone makes the question C++, not C! Identical syntax or calling functions from any C library does not make a program C! Whoever told you different does not know at least one of the languages well enough to do much more than a "Hello world" in that language.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I had 50 elements as for better understanding. I have started learning C and in visual studio when I add breakpoint I would be able to see what's going on during debug.

Comment: @Skynet I previously wrote the code and saved as C. when I built i got the following error

fatal error C1853: 'Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pch' precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: @Olaf My point was that the op is using `printf` instead of `std::cout`, same goes for `scanf` and `std::cin`. Doesn't that make it more C than C++? 1) I think you misunderstood me there. I never claimed that `#include <iostream>` has anything to do with the C standard. `iostream` is for C++ and `stdio.h` is for C.

Comment: @IanAbbott I re wrote the code and added int LinearSort(); above return 0 .

I built and no error is seen. But I the function is not calling LinearSort(). When I put breakpoint on the int LinearSort(); the code executed till printf("%d\n",sort[i]); and goes to return 0;.

Comment: @Skynet: Again: Relevant is how you compile! Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics - think about this! Would using C functions from Ada program make the program a C program??

Comment: Adding `int LinearSort();` above `return 0;` is just adding another declaration. You need to actually _call_ the function rather than just _declare_ it a second time. It doesn't help that you have two incompatible declarations of the `LinearSort()` function. The compiler is probably not complaining about that because you said you are compiling in C++ mode, so it will 'overload' different functions with the same name. I suggest compiling in C mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right way and your code needs only a little tweeking. Others have given valuable suggestions, most of which I won't repeat.

First the definition of your `LinearSort()`. You are passing a number of variables (i..k) that we call *local variables* and that should not be passed. Local variables are only used by your function and are declared inside the function. The proper definition now becomes:

```
void LinearSort(int a, int sort[]);   // prototype; put in header file or above main

void LinearSort(int a, int sort[])    // function itself
{
    int i, j, k;                      // local variables
```

Then you must call it from your main, after you read all the data. Call it like:

```
LinearSort(10, sort[]);
```

You passs 10 for `a` because you read a fixed number of integers; would you have read an arbitrary number (but less than 50), you would have passed a variable with this amount.

For your information: you pass the array variable `sort[]` but note that this name `sort` is the same in your main and in your function. There is no need and this just coincidence.

As for the sort algorithm, it seems based on bubble sort but uses for-loops. That is at least unusual and probaby wrong; the outer loop must go as many times as is needed until no more elements have been exchanged; however, a for loop normally executes a fixed number of times, so you see why this is probably wrong. I suggest you read about bubble sort.

Answer (score -2):

First, remove this statement

```
int LinearSort();
```

As you have already declared the function in header file and header is included in all files.
you should call `LinearSort()` with proper argument in your `main()` , after `scanf()` . And in your `LinearSort()` function, like this

```
int main()
{
    int sort[50];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    int a = 0;

    printf("Enter 10 Numbers");

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) 
    {
        scanf_s("%d",&sort[i]);
    }

    LinearSort(i, j, k,  a, sort);

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) 
    {
        printf("%d\n",sort[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And in LinearSort(), inside for loop,i don't see any specific use of `else` statement.

Comment: I re wrote the code and added int LinearSort(); above return 0 . I built and no error is seen. But I the function is not calling LinearSort(). When I put breakpoint on the int LinearSort(); the code executed till printf("%d\n",sort[i]); and goes to return 0

Comment: I wrote the main() for your reference, try this.

Comment: thank you. the code works gr8. Initially i add LinearSort(int i, int j,int  k,int  a, int sort[]); and got the error type 'int' unexpected. thats where I got struck.

my assumption is I used else , if the input numbers are same like 5,5,6,6, then the execution of if loop can be avoided for sorting those 4 numbers. I am sorry if I am wrong.